# Prove $99^{100}>100^{99}$ using binomial theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove $0<(1+\frac{1}{n})<3$ and hence prove $99^{100}>100^{99}$.

I did the first part and showed $0<\frac{1}{n^{n-1}}\le3$ and hence $0<(1+\frac{1}{n})<3$. But for the second bit, I don't know how to incorporate the first bit to help me prove th inequality.

Comment: Presumably you mean $0 < \big(1+\frac1n\big)^n < 3$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $n = 99$. Then you have $$100^{99}=(1 +n)^n=n^n\left (1+\frac1n\right)^n$$